# How to group array of dates and sum value by day, 1hour, 6hours, 8hours, week, month, and year?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, momentjs, lodash

I have the array of dates and I want to group dates by year, month, week, day, 6h, 8h and 1h and sum value. for example, I have the following array:

```
const data = [
  { x: "2021-10-17T14:38:45.540Z", y: 2 },
  { x: "2021-09-16T14:36:46.540Z", y: 1 },
  { x: "2021-01-04T14:35:46.540Z", y: 2 },
  { x: "2021-01-01T14:30:46.540Z", y: 1 },
  { x: "2020-02-01T06:28:47.520Z", y: 12 },
  { x: "2020-02-01T07:28:47.520Z", y: 12 },
  // ...
  { x: "2019-04-13T10:19:20.034Z", y: 20 },
  // ...
  { x: "2018-01-01T09:09:19.134Z", y: 4 },
  { x: "2017-01-01T12:09:19.034Z", y: 11 },
  { x: "2016-01-02T12:10:20.034Z", y: 24 },
  // ...
]
```

This is what I tried using momentjs and lodash [Group array of object by date](https://codesandbox.io/s/group-array-of-object-by-date-p1ioi?file=/src/index.js)

for year I got this result and the problem some years like 2018 and 2016 is not displayed:

```
 [
  {
    "color": "Blue",
    "value": 6,
    "label": "2021"
  },
  {
    "color": "Blue",
    "value": 24,
    "label": "2020"
  },
  {
    "color": "Blue",
    "value": 1212,
    "label": "2019"
  },
  {
    "color": "Blue",
    "value": 11,
    "label": "2017"
  }
]
```

Expected output for year:

```
[
      {
        "color": "Blue",
        "value": 6,
        "label": "2021"
      },
      {
        "color": "Blue",
        "value": 24,
        "label": "2020"
      },
      {
        "color": "Blue",
        "value": 1212,
        "label": "2019"
      },
      {
        "color": "Blue",
        "value": 10,
        "label": "2018"
      },
      {
        "color": "Blue",
        "value": 11,
        "label": "2017"
      },
      {
        "color": "Blue",
        "value": 48,
        "label": "2016"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @pilchard It should show every year ordered from the last to the oldest.

Comment: What about your hour groupings?

Comment: these data will be displayed in a histogram chart  about hour it should group data by hour  from 1 am to 2 am sum data

for example:
`{
    "color": "Blue",
    "value":  110,
    "label": "13/04/2019 1am to 2am"
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with a standard 'group-by' using reduce, here accumulating into an object and returning an array using `Object.values()`.

I've declared a simple `get_date_parts` helper to parse the ISO date strings which should be ample for grouping, but you can use a Date object for more complicated label formats if need be.

Here is the year grouping, the pattern can be adapted to all your other groupings, though you'll need to do a little arithmetic to determine hour ranges.

```js
const data = [{ x: '2021-10-17T14:38:45.540Z', y: 2 }, { x: '2021-09-16T14:36:46.540Z', y: 1 }, { x: '2021-01-04T14:35:46.540Z', y: 2 }, { x: '2021-01-01T14:30:46.540Z', y: 1 }, { x: '2020-02-01T06:28:47.520Z', y: 12 }, { x: '2020-02-01T07:28:47.520Z', y: 12 }, { x: '2019-04-13T10:19:20.034Z', y: 20 }, { x: '2018-01-01T09:09:19.134Z', y: 4 }, { x: '2017-01-01T12:09:19.034Z', y: 11 }, { x: '2016-01-02T12:10:20.034Z', y: 24 },];

function get_date_parts(iso_string) {
  const [year, month, day, hr, min, sec] = iso_string.split(/\D/g);

  return { year, month, day, hr, min, sec };
}

function group_by_year(arr) {
  return Object.values(
    arr.reduce((a, { x: date_string, y: value }) => {
      const { year } = get_date_parts(date_string);
      (a[year] ??= { color: 'Blue?', value: 0, label: year }).value += value;

      return a;
    }, {}),
  );
}

const grouped_by_year = group_by_year(data).sort((a, b) => +b.label - +a.label);

console.log(grouped_by_year);
```

or by month, also showing an alternative to [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) for initial assignment to `a[key]`.

```js
const data = [{ x: '2021-10-17T14:38:45.540Z', y: 2 }, { x: '2021-09-16T14:36:46.540Z', y: 1 }, { x: '2021-01-04T14:35:46.540Z', y: 2 }, { x: '2021-01-01T14:30:46.540Z', y: 1 }, { x: '2020-02-01T06:28:47.520Z', y: 12 }, { x: '2020-02-01T07:28:47.520Z', y: 12 }, { x: '2019-04-13T10:19:20.034Z', y: 20 }, { x: '2018-01-01T09:09:19.134Z', y: 4 }, { x: '2017-01-01T12:09:19.034Z', y: 11 }, { x: '2016-01-02T12:10:20.034Z', y: 24 },];

function get_date_parts(iso_string) {
  const [year, month, day, hr, min, sec] = iso_string.split(/\D/g);

  return { year, month, day, hr, min, sec };
}

function group_by_month(arr) {
  return Object.values(
    arr.reduce((a, { x: date_string, y: value }) => {
      const { year, month } = get_date_parts(date_string);
      const key = `${year}/${month}`;
      // using logical nullish assignment
      //(a[key] ??= { color: 'Blue?', value: 0, label: key }).value += value;

      // or written out long hand
      if (a[key] === undefined) {
        a[key] = { color: 'Blue?', value: 0, label: key };
      }

      a[key].value += value;

      return a;
    }, {}),
  );
}

const grouped_by_month = group_by_month(data).sort((a, b) => b.label.localeCompare(a.label));

console.log(grouped_by_month);
```

For the groupings that are not directly represented in the date you can use some simple arithmetic.

```js
function get_date_parts(iso_string) {
  const [year, month, day, hr, min, sec] = iso_string.split(/\D/g);

  return { year, month, day, hr, min, sec };
}

const date_string = '2020-02-07T07:28:47.520Z';

const { year, month, day, hr } = get_date_parts(date_string);

// week in the month
const week = Math.floor((parseInt(day, 10) - 1) / 7);
const week_label = `${year}/${month} - week ${week + 1}`;
console.log({ week_label, week });

// hour range
const range_size = 8;
const range = Math.floor(parseInt(hr, 10) / range_size);
// range times
const range_start = `${(range * range_size).toString().padStart(2, '0')}:00`;
const range_end = `${(range * range_size + range_size).toString().padStart(2, '0')}:00`;
const range_label = `${day}/${month}/${year} ${range_start}-${range_end}`;

console.log({ range_label, range });
```

Comment: ty I'll tried it and about the hour 
day 1 from  0am to 1am and 1am to 2am ...  
day 2 from  0am to 1am  ...

Comment: If i want to group by month do i only change a[year] to a[month]  ? 
in your example it does not group correctly.  
  `{
    "color": "Blue",
    "value": 42,
    "label": "2021/01"
  }`

in this example for the year 2021 there is 3 months  10, 09 and 01  

It should be:
`{
    "color": "Blue",
    "value": 3,
    "label": "2021/01"
  }`

Comment: `{month}` only returns the month, so if you want year and month you can define a key based on both `const { year, month } = get_date_parts(date_string); const key = \`${year}/${month}\`;` and then use that in the assign `a[key]` and for the label. But you'll need to adust later sorting for example `.sort((a, b) => b.label.localeCompare(a.label))`

Comment: and about the value ? 
the label is not the problem I have already displayed the year with the month.

in our example in the year 2021 there is 3 months 
It should be :
`{
    "color": "Blue",
    "value": 2,
    "label": "2021/10"
  },
  {
    "color": "Blue",
    "value": 1,
    "label": "2021/09"
  },
  {
    "color": "Blue",
    "value": 3,  // not  42
    "label": "2021/01"
  }`

Comment: Added another snippet, I'm not getting `42`? (I would probably make a single group_by that accepts arguments as to what portions/ranges to sort by instead of defining a bunch of individual functions)

Comment: ty, sorry mb 
the  const `key = `${year}/${month}`;` did the job

Comment: what do i change to group by week ? 
I did this to group by day :
`const key = `${year}/${month}/${day}`;`

Comment: You'll need to do some arithmetic to determine week, `const week = Math.floor(parseInt(day, 10) / 7);`

Comment: how to change this Syntax to a normal javascript ?
`(a[key] ??= { color: 'Blue?', value: 0, label: key }).value += value;`

Comment: `if (a[key] === undefined) { a[key] = { color: 'Blue?', value: 0, label: key }; } a[key].value += value;` I've added it to the 'month' example snippet

Comment: in arr.reduce  if I want to  set the   `a[year].value  =  last value - first value `
how to do that ?

Comment: I want change the sum value to be  a[year].value = last value - first value

Comment: lol at `color: blue?`